# Debian PHP 5.3 APD compile problems

Tags: php, debian, pecl

I've been trying to install [APD](http://pecl.php.net/package/apd) on Debian using `pecl install apd`. However, the command fails when entering the make stage:

```
make
/bin/sh /src/apd-1.0.1/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/src/apd-1.0.1 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/src/apd-1.0.1/include -I/src/apd-1.0.1/main -I/src/apd-1.0.1 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c -o php_apd.lo 
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/src/apd-1.0.1 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/src/apd-1.0.1/include -I/src/apd-1.0.1/main -I/src/apd-1.0.1 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_apd.o
/src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c: In function ‘zif_override_function’:
/src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c:615: warning: ‘zend_get_parameters_ex’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/php5/Zend/zend_API.h:222)
/src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c: In function ‘zif_rename_function’:
/src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c:669: warning: ‘zend_get_parameters_ex’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/php5/Zend/zend_API.h:222)
/src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c: In function ‘zif_apd_set_pprof_trace’:
/src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c:792: warning: ‘zend_get_parameters_ex’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/php5/Zend/zend_API.h:222)
/src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c: In function ‘apd_zend_startup’:
/src/apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c:967: error: ‘struct _zend_compiler_globals’ has no member named ‘extended_info’
make: *** [php_apd.lo] Error 1
```

Downloading the source, `phpize`ing and compiling myself leads to the same thing.

And help with why this is and how to get around it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

APD doesn't compile with PHP 5.3. See [bug](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16780).

Try apply [patch](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16780). Edit apd-1.0.1/php_apd.c, change this line:

```
CG(extended_info) = 1;
```

to

```
CG(compiler_options) |= ZEND_COMPILE_EXTENDED_INFO;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's "GC..." and not "CG..."? Because I downloaded apd 1.0.1 and there's just "CG..." :)